# Federated Authentication - two cookies, first cookie has closing xml tag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating the authentication cookies for a site using the code `FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(token);`

The token is quite big, so the cookie is split across two cookies. 99% of the time everything works correctly, here is an example of the two cookies from a successful login once they have been Base64 decoded:

WebSiteAuth:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SecurityContextTokenp1:Id="_e00ce4ab-> 2439-48d3-a1cd-f6a31180d02f-B99934A3DBEDB9B3EA191AB595FA8011" xmlns:p1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512"><Identifier>urn:uuid:adbfc4e1-c4a1-4882-9980-aa59431cdf48</Identifier><Cookie xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/security">ENCRYPTED_COOKIE_VALUE
```

WebSiteAuth1:

```
ENCRYPTED_COOKIE_VALUE</Cookie></SecurityContextToken>
```

But sometimes the user is encountering the following error:

> Exception information: 
>       Exception type: FormatException 
>       Exception message: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or
>   an illegal character among the padding characters.     at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32
>   inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)    at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
>   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(SessionSecurityToken&
>   sessionToken)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs eventArgs)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I logged the user's cookies at the time that the error was thrown, and here is what the cookies looked like after I Base64 decoded them.

WebSiteAuth:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SecurityContextToken p1:Id="_3518f851-bbec-4bb3-b7bb-c4c9bd9165e2-978AD0895E2683747B7CAFF4F1C7131B" xmlns:p1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512"><Identifier>urn:uuid:dd9a6856-9bd1-486c-9f5c-e980fbcc3b02</Identifier><Cookie xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2006/05/security">ENCRYPTED_COOKIE_VALUE</Cookie></SecurityContextToken>
```

WebSiteAuth1:

```
ENCRYPTED_COOKIE_VALUE</Cookie></SecurityContextToken>
```

As you can see, the difference is that the first cookie has closing tags `</Cookie></SecurityContextToken>`which should not be there, because the xml is closed in the second cookie.

I think that this is what is causing the error.

Does anyone have experience of this problem? Or any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to reduce the size of the cookie.

There is a setting on the SessionSecurityToken which is called IsReferenceMode. So I set this to be true. This means that the cookie is stored on the server and only a reference to this 'server cookie' is stored on the user's machine. This means that the cookie is much smaller, and is not split into two cookies, which avoids the problem I had where the first cookie chunk sometimes randomly included closing xml tags.

The downside to this approach is that when the application pool is restarted, then the customer loses their cookie, even if they set that the cookie should be persistant. To work around this I was able to inherit from the SessionSecurityTokenCache class and override the AddOrUpdate, Get and Remove methods to use the database as a backup store, so the token can be retrieved even if the session is cleared.

I adapted the thinktecture model which is here:
https://github.com/identitymodel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel

There is a good blog explaining the basics here:
https://brockallen.com/2013/02/21/server-side-session-token-caching-in-wif-and-thinktecture-identitymodel/